# Javascript cookies is not working on some PC

Tags: javascript, cookies

```
function rememberMe(){
    if($log("#rememberMeCheck").is(":checked")){
    var encrypted = CryptoJS.AES.encrypt($log("#password").val(), "pw");
    document.cookie = 'un='+ $log("#loginID").val()+';';
    document.cookie = 'pw='+ encrypted+';';
}
    else{
    document.cookie = "un=; expires=Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:00 UTC";
    document.cookie = "pw=; expires=Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:00 UTC";
}
```

This is the remember me check code. Using this I'm trying to implement remember me check for login page but the problem is the code working fine one some PC while it is not working on most PC. I have checked cookies setting on every PC cookie is enable but surprisingly not working on every PC. what the problem is ??

And what is the default time of cookies expiry if i not set it as in above code.

Comment: Are you sure it's a "pc" problem and not actually a browser problem?

Comment: pc means different computer's browsers:)

Comment: So same browser on different computers?

Comment: yes chrome on most of the pc